# Error CUDA mining: an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: mining

While mining after a while i got this error message

"Error CUDA mining: an illegal memory access was encountered" or
"Runtime error - ethash_cuda_miner::search, line 365"

the miner works for some time then the error comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to turn down the overclock and upgrade the Nvidia drivers. Fixed the problem.